# SQL server database design question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Users table and a Totals table which has an integer field for the total number of users. I thought about writing a console app that counts the Users table and then updates the Totals table. And then make a Task scheduler events that executes this app every 10 minutes. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify why you need a Totals table.  Is there a business requirement for it?  Doing a record count of "Users" will not have a performance impact - it's an extremely fast operation.

Comment: It has a few other system stats besides the user total and it doesn't have to be in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Totals table a view, so it doesn't need to be updated at all?

or ...

Update the Totals table with ON INSERT triggers on the Users table?

Comment: This is exactly what triggers were made for.